# Passing results to a a variable

Tags: xquery

Alright let me begin by saying I am completely new to XQuery. I started learning it only 2 days ago. 
Now my task involves using 3 separate xml files which essentially contain what would be tables.

The first file named dependent.xml contains these fields: essn, dependent_name, relationship.

The second file named employees.xml contains these fields: fname, lname, ssn, dno

The third file named department.xml contains these fields: dname, dnumber, mgrssn

So the relationships between these tables are: essn = ssn, ssn = mgrssn and dno = dnumber.

I need to return a list of all dependents, along with their corresponding employee and the corresponding manager of those employees. This is what my code looks like so far:

```
{
    for $d in doc("../company/dependent.xml")//dependent,
        $e in doc("../company/employee.xml")//employee
    where $d/essn = $e/ssn
    return
      <dependent
      name="{ $d/dependent_name }"
      fname="{ $e/fname }" lname="{ $e/lname }"
      />
}
```

This gives me a list of all dependents and their corresponding employee, so everything is good up to this point.

The problem is that the managers are also employees so their names are in the employee table. So I need to match the dno of the employees who have dependents with the dnumber in the department table in order to get the mgrssn of those departments and then match those mgrssn back with the employee ssn to get the manager names.

My idea is to store the dno of the employees with dependents which I'm getting from my code in a **variable** and then use that variable to get the managers for those departments and the use it like so:

```
{
    for $d in doc("../company/department.xml")//department,
        $e in doc("../company/employee.xml")//employee
    where $d/mgrssn = $e/ssn and $d/dnumber = $**variable**
    return
      <manager
      fname="{ $e/fname }" lname="{ $e/lname }"
      />
}
```

Problem is I have no idea how to do that and I realize that this would be on a separate for loop. Is there a way that I can do all this in one for loop? 
Also If there is an easier way to do what I need then I'm open to suggestions too :)

Comment: can you provide links to the XML file or example XML in your question?

Comment: This is one entry from the dependent file.
<dataroot>
<dependent>
<essn>123456789</essn>
<dependent_name>Alice</dependent_name>
<relationship>daughter</relationship>
</dependent>
</dataroot>

Employee file. 
<dataroot>
<employee>
<fname>John</fname>
<lname>Smith</lname>
<ssn>123456789</ssn>
<dno>5</dno>
</employee>
</dataroot>

Department file. 
<dataroot>
<department>
<dname>Headquarters</dname>
<dnumber>1</dnumber>
<mgrssn>888665555</mgrssn>
</department>
<department>
<dname>Administration</dname>
<dnumber>4</dnumber>
<mgrssn>987654321</mgrssn>
</department>
</dataroot>

Comment: I figured it out no further help needed. Thanks anyways.